# How to build Quasar app for ARM64 architecture on M1 Mac

Tags: electron-builder, quasar, apple-silicon, apple-m1

Can anyone help me? I can't figure out how to build an electron quasar app (for production) using the ARM64 Apple Silicon architecture. I've tried everything...

Answer (score 2):

Have same problem with quasar + cordova.
The workaround that works for me is:

1. Make **quasar build ...** command - build fails with error related to ARM64
2. Open `scr-cordova/platforms/ios/yourproject.xcworkspace` with XCode
3. Run build on XCode

After these steps I'm able to run app on device and make build for publishing